# PHP File Header Template increase version number

Tags: phpstorm

As an IDE I use PhpStorm and my php file header looks like

```
    * File: system -> lib -> response.php
    * Date:  16.06.2016
    * Version: 4220
    *
    * Copyright
```

Is there a plugin for PhpStorm or any other solution to increase the version number when saving the file?

Comment: Nope. Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7178

Comment: Why you need version number when saving the file? Maybe you mean a version in version system?